# Cell fracture and animating rigid bodies

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

Could anyone please explain to me how to achieve this something like this:

I have a fractured sphere on top of a table and I want to animate it rolling of-of it and then exploding into pieces only when it hits the ground.

Can't find a proper solution to achieve something like this. I was thinking about setting the "animated" checkbox on all of the fractures but I can't find a way to do all of them at the same time. ( CTRL+L -> "Animation Data"  does the job but it also makes every single fractured cell to get into the same spot so my "rolling" animation fails).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show you work in well chosen screen captures.   This will clarify you question and allow answerers to possibly shorten their answers and avoid tutorial information.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this with the help of the Fracture Modifier Build of blender. You can find more info and download it here:

http://graphicall.org/1148

I also included the steps in a text file inside the modified blend. Open this blend only in the Fracture Modifier Build or you may experience crashes and data loss in the blend.

[image]